Different Output for Same Input in C Program: Struct Array Initialization
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with a C program involving struct array initialization. Despite providing the same input values for both the x and y members of a struct point array, I'm observing different outputs. Here's a simplified version of the code:
#include<stdio.h>

struct point {
    int x, y;
};

int main() {
    struct point arr[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &arr[i].x, &arr[i].y);
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", arr[1].x, arr[1].y);
    return 0;
}

I'm providing the same input values for both x and y, but the output differs for x and y when printed. Could someone please explain why this is happening? I'm perplexed by this behavior and would appreciate any insights or explanations.
Thank you!
I wrote a C program that initializes an array of struct point with 10 elements. Each element has x and y integer members. In the program, I used a loop to read two pairs of integers from the user as input for the x and y members of the first two elements of the array.
What I Expected:
Since I provided the same input values for both x and y, I expected the output values for x and y to be the same when printed.

This is going to be hard, if not impossible, to replicate. The code you show is fine. Are you sure it's a [mre]? Did you copy-paste the correct code? What is your exact input and output? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete input and output.

Your code is fine. The problem is elsewhere. Read the other comments closely and [edit] the question accordingly.

Are you getting the same problem with the code you've posted here?  Because I cannot replicate the issue with this code.  Show us exactly how you're running the program, what your inputs are, and what your outputs are.

There is no initialization happening in this code.  I suspect this is actually a question about scanf.  As with all questions about scanf, the correct answer is "stop using scanf".

You don't test the return value from scanf() so you don't know whether the data was read correctly.

Initialize the array so no junk values are printed.
Check the return from scanf. In this example, if the return is not 2 there is a scanning problem.
#include<stdio.h>

struct point {
    int x, y;
};

int main() {
    struct point arr[10] = { 0}; // initialize array

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if ( 2 != scanf("%d %d", &arr[i].x, &arr[i].y)) { // check return from scanf
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem scanning i = %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", arr[1].x, arr[1].y);
    return 0;
}  

With an input of 2 3 4 5 the output is 4 5.
An input of 2,3,4,5 outputs problem scanning i = 0.
